# Image GridView within ScrollView

Tags: flutter

I want to create a scrollable page that contains some intro widgets, then a grid view that loads images from my backend as the person is scrolling. Think of Instagram on mobile (some text then grid view).

Having a scrollable within a scrollable resulted in a weird UX. Are there recomendation on how to deal with this kind of issues or maybe a better alternative?

Comment: use [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) that has `SliverToBoxAdapter` and `SliverGrid` as one of the `slivers: ...`

Comment: Do you have a mini example illustrating your solution please?

Comment: check the link I posted